# How to build an app with 2D graphics on Android?

Tags: android, graphics, libgdx, 2d

I want to build an app like [this](https://youtu.be/lHqg620u18Q) for Android using Kotlin, but I don't know where to start. It's not a game, but it has sort of gamification, so I don't know if it's ok to use a game library like libGDX.

Also, I want to build something as simple and easy as possible, 'cause I have no time and less than a year of Android experience.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If it's just the 2D UI you want to emulate, Android Views or libGDX would both be suitable for building this kind of UI. You can read up a bit on each to see what you think fits better. But if you're going to be using 3D, I would go with libGDX to begin with for everything.